# What does "the book was drenched" mean, from the first page of a scanned book?

Tags: meaning-in-context, subcontinental-english, sentence-meaning

The first printed page in the [scanned online version of *Analytical Solid Geometry* by Shanti Narayan](https://archive.org/details/analyticalsolidg032493mbp) says, "the book was drenched". I'm positive it doesn't have anything to do with wetness. So what does it mean here?
(There's nothing else written on the page. There are a couple of blank pages before and after this printed page.)

[image: Screencap of scanned book]

All the examples I've found are from **Osmania University Library in Hyderabad**. Could this be a term specific to Indian-English or a mistranslation from Hindi or another Indian language?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full context of this phrase. It's your responsibility as the questioner to provide the context in the body of the question itself (bear in mind that one day or another, that link may break, which would render your question meaningless to future readers; it's also simply courteous to do the legwork yourself when asking others to answer your question).

Comment: @DanBron thank you for stating your concern. The question is complete in itself though. Link is just a supplement.

Comment: Absent context, it simply means "the book was drenched" with the conventional, dictionary meanings of those words. That's all anyone can call you.

Comment: As Dan noted, there isn't enough context in the question. Why are you positive it doesn't have anything to do with wetness?

Comment: @rjpond very unlikely that anyone would scan a wet book. They would leave it for a week to dry out. Otherwise the pages would tear, they would stick to the scanner, etc.

Comment: I looked at about a dozen scans with this odd tag, and they all derived from the library of Osmania University in Hyderabad. I suspect a mistranslation of *this book has been scanned* or *uploaded* or something of that sort from Hindi or Telugu.

Comment: @StoneyB How can we leave it at that?  You're probably right, but I want to know the people at Osmania University meant!

Comment: It should be noted that two different browsers I tried bring you in on the title page.  You have to page backwards several pages to get to what I presume is supposed to be the inside front cover to find these words.  When you get there they don't make any sense.  Best guess I can make is that it's saying that the book was water-damaged.

Comment: @ab2 I suggest you put this to someone fluent both in English and in a number of Indian languages.

Comment: @StoneyB thank you for your research. I am fluent in Telugu, Hindi and even English for that matter. This word doesn't have anything to do with Indian languages as far as I can tell. Others, I'm positive it's not about wetness because that doesn't make sense! In what scenario will it be printed inside the book, after it got wet, and then digitised too?!

Comment: @yathish What about ab2's answer below, indicating that what is meant is something like 'discarded' or 'jettisoned' or 'deaccessioned'? Do you know of any Indian language in which the word for 'soak' or 'submerge' overlaps with a term like that?

Comment: @StoneyB I've accepted ab2's answer for now. I'm looking for an original source on a post made inside the link. I don't reckon university folk would insert a Hindi/Telugu word in the middle of an English sentence (no, I can't think of any such related word). In any case I left the last part of the now edited question untouched - so that any possible link to Indian languages mayn't be ruled out. If you go through the link shared by ab2, a relation to Indian language seems even less likely.

Comment: I'm from India and I'm a jack of 6 languages. I've never heard such an expression. And my Google Fu didn't help much either.

Comment: This isn't a question about the English language, the plain meaning of the words is not the issue, it is clearly some "code" that was only meaningful to whoever scanned and uploaded the books. This question should be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @yathish The text in question was not printed inside the book, any more than “OU_164820” was printed in the book. That is automated text presumably added by the scanning software when the book was scanned. This is indicated by the fact that the default view (as Hot Licks says) jumps to the actual title page, and by the fact that (like the text on the facing page) it is much sharper than the actually printed text. The first spread presumably does not exist in the real book at all, and it may well mean that the book had gotten drenched at some point before being scanned.

Comment: This begins to remind me of a certain [***"little yellow axe"***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/395382/which-word-begins-with-y-and-looks-like-an-axe-in-this-picture), @Dan Bron... is that the meaning of [*covfefe?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/391945/what-does-covfefe-exactly-mean)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about mistranslations from other languages or non-standard English are off-topic here.

Comment: "I'm positive it doesn't have anything to do with wetness."  Why? that's bizarre.  it obviously just means the (original) book got soaked, drenched.

Comment: This Q just has nothing to do with the English language.  The one and only meaning of drenched is trivially found in a dictionary.  (If "drenched" is some sort of specific corporate or software terminology in the system at hand - so what?  Who cares?)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based upon the erroneous belief "I'm positive it doesn't have anything to do with wetness.", when it clearly does.

Comment: @Greybeard Let's assume drenched here indeed means the book fell in water. That would mean the book was scanned before it was drenched (because all the pages inside the scanned version look intact) and later this page at the beginning was added to indicate it was drenched. Possible, but seems unlikely to me..

Comment: @yathish Wetness is not only associated with water. It could be some sort of liquid preservative treatment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an official source, but according to [Charles Wm Dimmick on alt.folklore.urban Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/alt.folklore.urban/TJE13-AGPGQ/T-Q8GGAbF68J), the explanation is more plausible than that the book got wet.

> It turns out that if I wait another few minutes the actual book is
>   there, but the "THIS BOOK IS DRENCHED" =A0is the first thing to appear.
>   Further research shows that this message shows up on about 40-50 books
>   which were digitized by Osmania University, and means that immediately
>   after digitizing the book they purged the physical book from their
>   collection.

**Addition: Evidence that drenched means water damage:**  From [Cyber Diary: Faceless Libraries in a Facebook Age](http://sibi-cyberdiary.blogspot.com/2013/04/faceless-libraries-in-facebook-age-read.html), (Scroll down to *Comment by Ananthanarayanan Vaidyanathan*):

> Recently the great Hindi  Prachar Sabha Library at Madras...one of the
>   biggest and greatest in  India suffered due to the flood....We find
>   that even in the digitized  versions of many valuable books..that many
>   pages are missing due to vandalism by borrowers or due to natural
>   calamities like moth attack and drenching and so on.  My heart sank
>   when some very valuable books downloaded from sites like Osmania
>   University contain the warning that the contents of the book are not
>   complete due to missing pages, drenching, etc.....

Comment: Awesome. I've posted on that group as well, just in case the OP there might reply.

Comment: I wonder why they used *drenched* to mean that. OED has no record of any similar usage.

Comment: I e-mailed the Osmania University Library (OUL) at their "contact us" e-mail address.  See here https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10737/should-this-question-about-this-book-is-drenched-be-closed/10739#10739 for my e-mail to OUL.  If it turns out that the books were water damaged, that will just show that the simplest explanation is often best!

Comment: 1) the quote you made makes no mention of getting wet. 2) following the link to the usenet archive, Dimmick is responding to someone who said "Maybe the original book got wet and now all the ebook copies don't 
work. " which is entirely speculative, and therefore not a definitive answer.

Comment: @Mitch I e-mailed OUL because I am dissatisfied with what we were able to find.  Either OUL will answer, and the mystery will be solved, or OUL will not answer and we should move on.

Comment: @ab2 I have no hopes on OUL checking it's mail. Much less on reverting to it! If someone who finds this post, who also happens to live nearby OUL, contacts the library in person then we may dig out something.

Comment: @yathish It was an obvious thing to do and took only a minute.  If they don't reply, little will have been lost.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't mean anything idiomatic in English as far as I am aware, my best guess is that it somehow indicates the program, user, or method that was used to scan/rip the book and upload the contents to archive.org.

For comparison, see [this copy of War and Peace](https://archive.org/details/warandpeace030164mbp), which also contains a cryptic header at the top of its text file:

> TEXT FLY
>
> WITHIN THE
>
> BOOK ONLY

Whatever that means. I assure you, this is not a part of the original Tolstoy.

Here's another, [The Bantu Speaking Tribes Of South Africa](https://archive.org/details/bantuspeakingtri032916mbp), that also begins with "THE BOOK WAS DRENCHED".

So no, it wasn't added by the author or publisher, it was added later sometime in the scanning/OCR/upload process. Just ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for your time and research. The point of this question is not whether the author included it. Nor is it about the importance of it. It's just a curiosity behind what could have been meant by whosoever put it in the book. To that extent, your answer doesn't help.

Comment: @yathish My point was that this isn't a question about the meaning of the English language, this is a question about the methods and practices of a group that scans and uploads books. I found examples of other uploads that demonstrate that there is some other meaning, besides the obvious, attached to these phases. Whether my guess about what it *actually* means is correct or not, I have no idea. But in any case this question is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Cryptic indeed but not too cryptic: "TEXT FLY

WITHIN THE

BOOK ONLY" probably refers to any text present on the usually blank [*flyleaf*](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=flyleaf+-band+-rock+-music&client=firefox-b&dcr=0&oq=flyleaf+-band+-rock+-music&gs_l=mobile-heirloom-serp.3...3279.9845.0.10337.13.13.0.0.0.0.549.3060.3j1j6j1j1j1.13.0....0...1.1.34.mobile-heirloom-serp..13.0.0.mBaqP-eF_pg) (very first page when we open the book) and might be informing the reader that it's been included as part of the book text.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the book was  *re**trenched.***

I know it is not encouraged to be speculative at ELU, but because real facts are lacking, I may be allowed to take up the context of somebody's comment elsewhere, referenced in the answer by @ab2 here, that 'this book was drenched' has something to do with getting rid of the physical copy after the book is digitised, as in

> this message shows up on about 40-50 books
> which were digitized (...) and means that immediately after digitizing the book they purged the physical book from their collection

and this part of the very next comment on the same page (in reply) by another user:

> Well, library space costs money and they're getting smaller and
> smaller.

On this basis, and especially because the comment seems to refer to the library of an Indian university,  I shall hypothesise that 'drenched' here could be an unintended [phonetic misspelling](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/402272/231519) of **retrenched** which is defined as follows by [Merriam-Webster dictionary online:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retrenchment)

> retrenchment [noun] :  reduction, curtailment; specifically :  a cutting of expenses

The books were *retrenched* to curtail the expense of storing the physical copies:

> This book was **retrenched.**

This type of spelling error can occur when the person writing it knows neither the word nor its spelling but is simply rendering a word *heard spoken* by somebody. If I or another Indian were to casually say 'retrenched', the 're' could be weak and there might be more emphasis on the second syllable (trenched), or maybe a lorry passed by outside with a heavy grinding of gears that obscured the 're' sound -- moreover some Indians tend to pronounce the *'t'* sound in the middle of words as a *'d'* sound -- somebody else could easily hear and render it phonetically in writing as 'drenched.'

Of course that person would not know the word 'drenched' or its meaning either.

> Head librarian says: when a book is scanned we need it to say on the first page, "the book was retrenched."
>
> The assistant hears an unknown word and phonetically types out another unknown word: *the book was drenched.*

---

On the other hand, an early [step in the recycling of paper](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=steps+to+recycle+paper&client=firefox-b&oq=steps+to+recycle+paper&gs_l=mobile-heirloom-serp.12...0.0.1.3668.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..34.mobile-heirloom-serp..8.3.641.W68FhOeK_m0) is to soak it in water for a few days...

> This book is going to be recycled. *This book was **drenched.***

This is much less likely because Indian universities are bureaucratically *very* serious places without any sense of wit or humor. *A University is a '**temple of learning**' where students come to acquire Knowledge for a better life -- this is no place for subtle linguistic wit and riddles -- keep your humor outside the Library Door!* So I leave you with [Dante's immortal quote](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=abandon+hope+all+ye+who+enter+here&client=firefox-b&dcr=0&oq=abandon+hope+all+ye+who+enter+here&gs_l=mobile-heirloom-serp.3..0l5.35629.36271.0.37408.3.3.0.0.0.0.341.828.0j1j0j2.3.0....0...1.1.34.mobile-heirloom-serp..1.2.486.NCcd_6zMRC0) until we can get a more factual answer.

---

Important note to would-be editors of my answer: since I should prefer to be subtle once in a while, please do not find, copy and paste-in Dante's immortal quote referred to ironically here. Let interested readers follow the link and learn more.

Answer (score -1):

The book was drenched
My wild intellectual informed guess

***Blueprinting***

Source https://science.howstuffworks.com/engineering/architecture/question321.htm
*Blueprinting is the older method, invented in 1842. The drawing to be copied, drawn on translucent paper, is placed against paper sensitized with a mixture of ferric ammonium citrate and potassium ferricyanide. The sensitized paper is then exposed to light. Where the areas of the sensitized paper are not obscured by the drawing, the light makes the two chemicals react to form blue. **The exposed paper is then washed in water.** This produces a negative image, with the drawing appearing in white against a dark blue background.*

In earlier times before the invention of modern photocopying technique, some process like blueprinting might have been employed to copy a book. As it involves "washing in water" the term "drenching" might have been then in vogue in library circles

The word drenching a book has its origin much before modern scanning techniques were invented. Therefore it is highly unlikely that it refers to **scanned** or **digitised**.It more likely means **copied**. Copied through some proces involving "washing in water" and therefore "drenching"

Comment: Hello, Shrikant. Guesses are not the sort of answers desired on ELU. Wild guesses, even less so. Even when they are claimed to be intellectual and informed.

Comment: As you yourself say, blueprinting was typically used for drawings. It is unlikely that a book would have been copied by blueprinting.